# How to test rspec subdomain constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, subdomain

My rspec controller tests are failing with a No Route Found error because I am using a subdomain constraint. I've looked at all solutions online and I implemented all the solutions below with no success, all in the before block:

```
@request.host = "api.127.0.0.1.xip.io"
```

and

```
@request.host = "api.lvh.me"
```

and

```
@request.host = "api.lvh.me:3000"
```

and

```
@request.stub(:subdomains).and_return(['api']); 
@request.host = "api.example"
```

and

```
@request.host = 'www.example.com'
```

My subdomain is `api`. When doing the actual requests, I am using `http://api.lvh.me:3000` as my app is still local and I haven't done any changes to my `/etc/hosts`. What is the problem here and how can I get the route to work with the `api` subdomain?

Comment: Why haven't you done any changes to your `/etc/hosts`? Is it something you want to avoid?

Comment: @etagwerker Because I did add `127.0.0.1   api.example.com` to `/etc/hosts`, and then put `@request.host = 'api.example.com'` in a `before(:each)` block in my rspec controller test, it still throws the same error. How would I modify the request given I edit my `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: can you add the test related to your code?

Comment: @etagwerker It's just: `describe "GET #index" do it "does something" do get :index end end`. It fails with no route error at `get :index`.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the content of your `config/routes.rb`?